# Insert SQL array

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to write an insert statement which would get data from an array.

I have two variables, one is BusinessID and one is BusinessType. A business can have multiple types. For example `BusinessType = (1,2,3,4,5)`, however BusinessID would only ever be a single number e.g. BusinessID = 1

Is there a function in mssql to be able to do something like;

```
for BusinessType in BusinessType
   insert into Business 
   Values(BusinessID,BusinessType)
```

This would ideally give me the result

```
BusinessID BusinessType
     1          1
     1          2
     1          3
     1          4
     1          5
```

Comment: Normally it's the responsibility of the application layer to translate that comma-separated list into a series of `INSERT` statements.

Comment: What is the SQL datatype of "BusinessType"?

Comment: BusinessType is an int currently, but it can be something else if needed.

Comment: You could look into user defined table types and pass in a table valued parameter, or you can split the string (which is not good for performance), or you can generate multiple insert statements (also not good for performance).

Comment: A table called `Business` should contain records where each record represents a "business" (whatever this is in your context). If that table `Business` has a column called `BusinessID`, then this should be the ID to identify one record (or one "business"). It doesn't seem to make sense to have multiple records in `Business` that have the same `BusinessID`. It seems you are trying to build a kind of bridge table combining "businesses" with "business types". You should think over your database design or at least your naming pattern.

Answer (score 1):

If not 2016, here is an inline approach to split your string

Uncomment the Insert line if satisfied with the results.

**Example**

```
Declare @BusinessID int = 1
Declare @Type varchar(max) = '1,2,3,4,5'  -- notice no ()'s

--Insert Into Business (BusinessID,BusinessType) 
Select BusinessID = @BusinessID
      ,BusinessType = B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'int')
 From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace(@Type,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
 Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
```

**Returns**

```
BusinessID  BusinessType
1           1
1           2
1           3
1           4
1           5
```